# Do python support generated objects?

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

for example, is there a difference between in performance:

```
for x in someFunc(): 
    print x
```

and

```
result = someFunc()
for x in result:
    print x
```

is the result is now generator object so the two case will operate the same ?

Comment: Have you tried this? I would not expect the same behaviour at all.

Comment: This is not a valid syntax of for loop in C++

Comment: It depends on what `someFunc` does and returns, but more importantly it depends on the language. None of the languages mentioned, as tags or in the body, can be expected to behave the same even for similar structures.

Comment: What's the difference between a duck?

Comment: I know the syntax is not the same, the question is about the case. In the second for. the result is not a functon - but I can't edit it.

Comment: I think you mistakenly have "for x in result():" and it should be "for x in result:"

Comment: In the future, please choose one relevant language tag, or if is language agnostic, then the language agnostic tag.

Comment: You can't even get a categorically "yes" or "no" answer even if using only *one* language. Take Python for example, what if the functions returns an iterable collection (string, list, etc.)? What if the function `yield` a result? There, in the same single language, you have *two* answers.

Comment: As mentioned before by Steephen, the first loop is no valid C++. However, if it is taken as pseudo code, I am pretty sure that it is possible to come up with a concrete implementation such that the function is called only once as well as with a different implementation where the function is called several times.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not true, it will behave the same for any *iterable* return from `someFunc`, whether or not it's an *iterator*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So even in the first case, if the function is a generator function yielding results every call, the function will only be called once?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, the function is called once and returns a generator object, which is then iterated over.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Taking e.g. the generator function `firstn` from [this tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), how will the returned generator object know what the next value will be, if it doesn't call the function again?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg as that article notes, *"Python provides generator functions as a convenient shortcut to building iterators."* - the *function itself* is only called once, it builds and returns the generator instance. Although the syntax used makes it easier to think about what happens, you aren't *really* calling the function repeatedly. You could write and use a decorator to count the calls to the function, if you like.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I still find it hard to believe that the function is called only once, the creation of the generator object must still call the function (albeit indirectly) multiple ties to get all the values doesn't it? Especially if the generated sequence is large, or the data is unpredictable. I can agree on that the function is only called once *directly*, but I refuse to believe that it won't be called multiple times.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, I'm not clear what distinction you're trying to draw. The code inside the function runs multiple times, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Something like that yes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ah, I see; I think we were talking at cross-purposes, apologies!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think so too, please accept my apologies as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some languages, you showed a python example, support *generators* that don't have a `return` statement, they `yield` a value on each iteration.

In Python, the statement:

```
result = someFunc()
```

makes `result` refer to a *generator object*, which you can then use the `next()` builtin to get the next value.

In the Python `for` loop the `next()` is called for you, so we iterate through a *lazy list* of values (a lazy list is where only one item at a time is provided).

So actually your statement:

```
result = someFunc()
for x in result:
    print x
```

*will* produce the same!  That is because `result` is a generator object: the name `result` is a bad choice.

Comment: Even if `someFunc` *is* a generator, the two forms would behave identically.

Comment: Correct, I was editing while you wrote the comment.

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++, it gets called always if the compiler couldn't optimize that piece of code. You could try this yourself:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

size_t getLength(char *s)
{   puts("Called");
    return strlen(s);
}

int main(void)
{   char s[] = "test";
    for(int i = 0; i < getLength(s); i++)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Called
Called
Called
Called
Called
```

Comment: On the other hand you have the new [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which is more like the syntax used in the question (`for (auto &i : someFunction()) { ... }`). Here the function will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python**, there is absolutely no difference between:

```
for x in someFunc(): 
    print x
```

and

```
result = someFunc()
for x in result:
    print x
```

Either way, whatever is returned from `someFunc` gets iterated over, each resulting item is assigned to `x` and `print`ed.

The only possible difference comes *after* the loop, where in the second form you can access `result`. This may be useful if it's e.g. a sequence (`list`, etc.), but probably not so much if it's a (now-exhausted) iterator. In the first form, there is no way to access the returned value from `someFunc` aside from the iteration over it.

Answer (score -1):

**In your examples**  in both cases the function is called once. This is because the **return** of the function is being used here as the data. For the example shown, first the function is called and the return data is used for the whole for loop. In the second example, you set the **return** of the function to a variable and use the variable for your for loop.

So in both cases, the same data will be used for the for loop. And yes it is the same for Java, C if the code is structured in that way.

Comment: You can't categorically say that the function will be called once, not with all the languages the OP is asking about. What about Python, where the function could `yield` a result?

Comment: @omertalmi If I answered your question and you understand the answer, click the accept button on my answer.

Comment: See @JoachimPileborg's comment

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg This is for function and method programming in general. I'm going off the examples he gave me.